# Facilities available during layovers by Air India

Tags: layovers, air-india, chennai, maa

I have a ticket from Bangalore to Port Blair Via Chennai, with a layover of 12h30m (arrival at chennai 17:10 and departure on next day at 5:00). Does Air India provide accommodation during this layover ?

Comment: Did you try asking them? Might be a quicker way to get an authoritative answer than asking here!

Answer (score 3):

Air India will not provide overnight accommodation on this route. I think All Nippon were the last to offer such a service, but even they have stopped it now

Comment: Just a one line comment without any sources? Would it be possible to mention any sources for that information?